# How to check the list of packages and applications installed along with the name of the users that installed them.?

Tags: command-line, package-management, users

I have a Ubuntu desktop which is accessed by many other users. Is there an option or a command to check all the packages/application that was installed by a particular user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script that parses authentication logs. The basic idea that any installation *attempt* requires authentication from sudo and polkit.

The script doesn't list whether or not installation attempt was successful or not - only the fact that user attempted to install something ; this feature might be added in future. The reason for that is difficulty in parsing - authentication attempts do list commands attempted, but apt and dpkg logs actually list what has been successful but don't mention who installed what.

The script can differentiate whether it was done via command-line or gui tools ( with `-c` and `-g` flags) as well as filtering by user (the `-u` flag).

The script should be a used as a tool by administrators for auditing software installation attempts ; the actual fact of  successful installation can be verified through filtering of `dpkg --get-selections`

The script can also be found on   [my github](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep)

```
<!-- language:bash -->

#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: April 4, 2016
# Purpose: filtering installation attempts
# Written for:
# Tested on:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo , 2016
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

ARGV0="$0"
ARGC=$#
print_usage()
{
cat << EOF
Usage: list_installs.sh [-c] [-g]  [-u username] [-h]

The script parses authentication logs and filters 
installation attempts based on whether they've been
done through gui, command-line, or particular 
user. Note that it lists all attempts at authentica-
tion for software installation. It doesn't show
whether or not the installation succeeded.

Installations done via gui tools typically use
polkit, so entries don't show exact item that
has been installed, only the tool used -
/usr/bin/software-center for example. Hence,
date-stamps still have to be cross checked with 
apt history logs

Note that authentication logs (auth.log) are
rotated as outlined in /etc/logrotate.conf ,
typically every 4 weeks. This may need to be
tuned by your system's administrator to list
installs over longer periods of time
EOF

}
dump_logs()
{
  find /var/log/auth.log.*.gz | sort  -r -V | xargs zcat > "$1" 
  cat /var/log/auth.log >> "$1"
}

generate_report()
{
  awk '$0~/.*apt-get.*/||/.*dpkg.*/||/.*org\.debian\.apt\.install-or-remove-packages.*/\
       {print $0;print "- - -"}' "$1"  > /tmp/report.tmp
  mv /tmp/report.tmp "$1"
}

gui_installs()
{
  awk '$0~/org\.debian\.apt\.install-or-remove-packages/\
       { printf "%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3;\
         for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){\
            if($i~/unix-user/){\
               printf " %s ",$i; };\
            if($i~/action/){\
              printf "%s\n",$(i+1); next  }\
         }\
       }' "$1"
}

cmd_installs()
{
  awk '$0~/.*apt-get.*/||/.*dpkg.*/{\
       printf "%s %s %s ",$1,$2,$3 ;\
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){\
          if($i~/sudo/||/pkexec/){\
             printf " %s ",$(i+1)};\
          if($i~/COMMAND/){\
            for(j=i;j<=NF;j++)\
               printf "%s ",$j\
          }\
       };
       printf "\n"  }' "$1"
}

parse_args()
{
 local OPTIND opt
 # no leading : means errors reported(which is what i want)
 # : after letter means options takes args, no letter - no args
 while getopts "cgu:h" opt
 do
   case ${opt} in
     c) cmd_installs "$DUMPFILE"
        ;;
     g) gui_installs "$DUMPFILE"
        ;;
     u) UNAME="${OPTARG}"
        echo ">>> CMD INSTALLS <<<"
        cmd_installs "$DUMPFILE" | grep $UNAME 
        echo ">>> GUI INSTALLS  <<<"
        gui_installs "$DUMPFILE" | grep $UNAME
        ;;
     h) print_usage
        ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" > /dev/stderr
        ;;
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
}


main()
{
  local DUMPFILE="/tmp/auth.dump"
  dump_logs "$DUMPFILE"
  generate_report  "$DUMPFILE"
  parse_args "$@"  
  rm "$DUMPFILE"
}
main "$@"
```

Comment: Big flaw however . . . If user logs in as `sudo -i` or `sudo su` their installations will go into `/var/log/apt/history.log` , which unfortunately doesn't record usernames. Probably an admin also has to manually check whether or not a user logged in as root , and then check whether there were any installations around that time